# LWC + Jest: Make assertions about an element's rendered style

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, lwc-dom

In a LWC project, I'm setting certain child component style properties from the parent component.  I want to test that an element in a child component shows up with those properties when it's rendered, based on a public reactive property that has been set.

The child component:

**myComponent.html**

```html
<template>
    <div style={headerStyle}>
        Some content...
    </div>
</template>
```

**myComponent.js**

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api backgroundColor;

    get headerStyle(){
        return 'background-color:' + this.backgroundColor';';
    }
}
```

**myComponent.test.js**

```js
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import myComponent from 'c/myComponent';

describe('myComponent tests', () => {

    it('renders the background color correctly', () => {

        const element = createElement('c-my-component', {
            is: myComponent
        });

        element.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

        // Add the component to the DOM
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        // Get the div
        let div = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');

        // Await async DOM updates
        return Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => {
                // ???
            })

    });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stumbled across the answer as I was writing up the question.

You can access an element's style properties ( ...drum roll... ) via its style property.

```js
return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        // This passes
        expect(div.style.backgroundColor).toBe('yellow');
    })
```